# SQL query to find the author of a specific blog post?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi i'm trying to pull the first_name of the user who was the author for a certain blog post from my database but having a bit of a problem. I'm really getting confused on how to join the two tables together and can't really find a simple explanation. Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goldhub_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `goldhub_email` (`email`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goldhub_post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
)
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT goldhub_user.first_name FROM goldhub_post
INNER JOIN goldhub_user ON goldhub_user.user_id = goldhub_post.user_id
WHERE goldhub_post.post_id = ?
```

Replace the `?` with the ID of the post.

Comment: Could you also use left join in this situation? Thanks

Comment: @Conor If you would use `LEFT JOIN` then posts that doesn't have a user_id tied to them would also show up, meaning the query would return `null` for those posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it would help me if you post the condition to get the author based on post

```
SELECT gu.first_name FROM goldhub_user gu
LEFT JOIN  goldhub_post gp
     ON gu.user_id = gp.user_id
WHERE gp.post_id = ?
AND gp.category_id = ?;
```